# An SQL query to display the count of distinct values of a single column into a single row

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

There is a table "OBJECTS" with one column "OBJECT_NAME" having three values: OBJ1, OBJ2, OBJ3.

Snapshot of the table OBJECTS is:

```
OBJECT_NAME
----------
OBJ3
OBJ1
OBJ2
OBJ1
OBJ1
OBJ2
```

Need to write a most efficient SQL query to output the count of the distinct object in the format as shown below. Make sure that performances are optimised and explain what was done for the optimization.

```
OBJ1_Count   OBJ2_COUNT   OBJ3_COUNT
--------------------------------- 
3              2           1
```

Comment: This is your task to perform. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Make sure you do it right...

Answer (score 0):

Your homework assignment marks should be given to me once i illustrate the example for your query :P. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 'OBJ1' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ1' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ2' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ2' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ3' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ2' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ3' AS NM FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBJ3' AS NM FROM DUAL
  ) PIVOT ( COUNT (NM) FOR NM IN ('OBJ1','OBJ2','OBJ3') );


---------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------

'OBJ1'  'OBJ2'  'OBJ3'
  2        3      3

---------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------
```